# Gremlin query - how to eliminate nested coalesce

Tags: gremlin, graph-databases, amazon-neptune

I have `person` vertex, `has_vehicle` edge and `vehicle` vertex which models vehicle ownership use case. The graph path is `person -> has_vehicle -> vehicle`.

I want to implement a Gremlin query which associates a vehicle to a person only if

- The person does not have a vehicle

AND

- The input vehicle is not associated with a person yet.

I followed the [fold-coalesce-unfold pattern](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/transactions-examples.html) and came out with following Gremlin query with nested coalesce

```
g.V().hasLabel('person').has('name', 'Tom').as('Tom').outE('has_vehicle').fold().coalesce(
  __.unfold(), // check if Tom already have a vehicle
  g.V().has('vehicle', 123).as('Vehicle').inE('has_vehicle').fold().coalesce(
    __.unfold(), // check if vehicle 123 is already associated with a person
    __.addE('has_vehicle').from('Tom').to('Vehicle') // associate the vehicle to Tom
  )
)
```

Is there a way to eliminate the nested coalesce? If I have multiple criteria, it would be too complex to write the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a case where a couple of `where(not(...))` patterns, rather than nesting `coalesce` steps works well. For example, we might change the query as shown below.

```java
g.V().hasLabel('person').has('name', 'Tom').as('Tom').
      where(not(outE('has_vehicle'))).
  V().has('vehicle', 123).as('Vehicle').
      where(not(inE('has_vehicle'))).
  addE('has_vehicle').from('Tom').to('Vehicle')
```

So long as the `V` steps do not fan out and yield multiple Tom or Vehicle nodes that should work and is easy to extend by adding more to the `where` filters as needed.

As as a side note, the `not` steps used above should work even if not wrapped by `where` steps, but I tend to find it just reads better as written.

This rewrite does make an assumption that you are able to tolerate the case where Tom already has a car and the query just ends there. In that case no vertex or edge will be returned. If you did a `toList` to run the query you would get an empty list back in that case however to indicate nothing was done.